# Debugging a React Native crash in release

Tags: react-native

I'm using [`react-native-tcp`](https://github.com/PeelTechnologies/react-native-tcp) and am experiencing a crash on Android that I'm unable to debug. Unfortunately, this only happens in release.

The stack trace I get is as follows:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
               Process: com.xx.xx, PID: 22986
               com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: unable to find socket, stack:
               d@664:708
               _onError@664:4582
               <unknown>@664:3790
               value@77:1364
               value@53:2778
               <unknown>@53:1013
               <unknown>@53:106
               value@53:985

                   at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:99)
                   at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseJavaModule$JavaMethod.invoke(BaseJavaModule.java:345)
                   at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:136)
                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Now, the Javascript stack trace is pretty cryptic (presumably due to minification and bundling), but it helpfully includes `_onError`, which in `react-native-tcp` is implemented as follows:

```
TcpSocket.prototype._onError = function(error: string): void {
  this._debug('received', 'error');

  this.emit('error', normalizeError(error));
  this.destroy();
};
```

The `normalizeError` call above maps to the `d` function in the stacktrace. I know this because I examined the bundled file generated during a build.

I understand why my code flow leads to an `unable to find socket` event, but what I don't understand is how this event eventually leads to an application crash. If it helps, this event is generated in the native (Android) component of `react-native-tcp` and propagates into the JS side.

I expected such an event to be reported to the listeners (if any) rather than crash the application.

Is it possible that events reported via React Native lead to a crash in some conditions - e.g. if there are no listeners, or if the event is an `Error` object, or something else?

How would I go about debugging this, given that it happens only in release?

Comment: Connect device to pc and open android studio, then run the app if it crashes then you can see the logs in the logcat.

Comment: @ParasWatts the exception stack trace that I pasted is taken from logs collected by logcat. It seems that the exception was ultimately thrown by React Native, but I can't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find an efficient debugging technique, but was able to debug the issue I had with good ol' prints.

The problem was that NodeJS (and apparently also React Native) have a behavior which I found peculiar: when an `error` event is emitted and there is no `error` listener, an unhandled exception is thrown. This is documented in the [NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html):

```
When an error occurs within an EventEmitter instance, the typical action is 
for an 'error' event to be emitted. These are treated as special cases 
within Node.js.

If an EventEmitter does not have at least one listener registered for the 
'error' event, and an 'error' event is emitted, the error is thrown, a stack 
trace is printed, and the Node.js process exits.

const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
myEmitter.emit('error', new Error('whoops!'));
// Throws and crashes Node.js
```

My problem is that I was removing the `error` listener in my code, because of a [`react-native-tcp` issue](https://github.com/PeelTechnologies/react-native-tcp/issues/47) that causes the `error` callback to be called twice when `connect` fails because no one is listening on the port.